# JavaScript is "run to completion". What is Java?

Tags: java, scheduling

If JavaScript is "run-to-completion". What is Java?

Is it preemptive multitasking because the Java runtime contains a scheduler that preempts running execution flows, allocating time on the CPU without worrying about the state of the threads?

Edit: I know Java is unrelated to JavaScript, but I do not know the correct terminology, so I chose to communicate through the use of analogy.

Comment: Look up daemon vs non-daemon threads as I *think* that this is what you're asking about.

Comment: Java is unrelated to Javascript. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I am asking: does the JRE have a preemptive multitasking control flow model?

Comment: I think you're using microspeak as googling tells me the term you're using is (apparently?) MS/CLR related and is just plain threads. Herein I think I'm going to second @hovercraft 's recommendation.

Comment: Which term is MS/CLR related?

Comment: Reading between the lines of your question, I think the answer is that Java is fully preemptive.  Most thread libraries these days are implemented with ordinary OS processes (because most process implementations are lightweight enough to be a "thread") and I'm sure the JVM uses a standard threading library (or even direct OS calls).

Comment: Thank you. Does the JRE contain a scheduler of its own, or does it delegate to the OS?

Comment: And thinking about this a bit more: your question is weird because most threads in Java (non-daemon threads) are fully preemptive *and* will always run to completion.  So maybe "both" is the best answer.  I'm still uncertain of your context though.

Comment: I can't swear this is always true but I'm pretty sure the most common implementations use the OS scheduler.

Comment: They won't always run to completion if they are preempted and subsequently a process-fatal error is thrown in another thread?

Comment: If a thread throws an exception, it has completed.  If a thread is waiting (preempted) and another thread throws an exception, the first thread will either complete or wait forever (unless it's a daemon thread).

Comment: Who said that JavaScript is "run-to-completion"? The JavaScript language doesn't say that. If you run JavaScript in a JVM, e.g. using the Nashorn engine in Java 8, it will be fully preempted, just like any other language or script running in JVM. JavaScript can run multi-threaded without problem. Now, *web browsers* may enforce a single-threaded execution model for web pages, but that has nothing to do with *JavaScript*.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that "single-threaded" is not the same thing as "run to completion."

Comment: @Andreas "Who said that JavaScript is 'run-to-completion'?" Section 8.4 of the spec, paragraph 2: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues This is the most ridiculously hostile response to a question I have ever had.

Comment: Most Java programmers are unfamiliar with the details of JavaScript.  `Once execution of a Job is initiated, the Job always executes to completion.`  Is that the phrase you are referring to?  Is there a difference between a "Job" and a thread?

Comment: Using Wikipedia's definition, a thread is "the smallest sequence of instructions managed by a scheduler". The JavaScript runtime uses the term "Job" to describe an item on the queue to be scheduled to be run on the single thread of execution (web workers I am ignoring for simplicity). So the scheduling mechanism of JavaScript can be said to be "run to completion" in the sense that a unit of execution (a Job in JavaScript) cannot be preempted. The terminology requires some translation, but I would like to know how the JRE schedules execution (if indeed it does).

Comment: I see.  So in JavaScript, even if a thread blocks (say waiting for IO to complete) no other threads will start a new Job until the current Job completes.  (In Java, we would probably call a Job a "task".)

Comment: In that context, Java thread are fully preemptable.  They work just like OS threads, as mentioned.

Comment: Finally, do you know if the JRE has a built-in scheduler, or does it leverage the OS by virtue of Java threads being real OS threads (or processes)?

Comment: I'm like 90% certain all Windows and *nix JVMs use the OS scheduler, as I mentioned already.  I don't know of any JVMs that use their own scheduler.

Comment: @BenAston The job execution model described in the ECMA documentation is like a single-threaded Java `Executor`, running one "Job" (JavaScript) / "Task" (Java) at a time. By comparison, Java is "run-to-completion" too, in that no other code can run in a Java `Thread` until the currently running Java code completes (normally or abnormally). This is independent of the support for multi-threading, which Java definitely has, but JavaScript doesn't have natively (in the spec). HTML 5 however does add multi-threading to JavaScript (Web Workers).